# Why do reference electrodes have porous frits or membranes as a salt bridge?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, reduction-potential

From what I understand, they act as a salt bridge between the reference electrode electrolyte and the analyte solution (in a potentiometric titration). But why do we use partially permeable membranes or frits instead of making a normal salt bridge for the reference half cell?

Comment: The answer is here on ResearchGate https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_function_of_porous_frit_for_reference_electrode

Comment: Hi there, the link is not opening - it redirects me to the researchgate.com/topics page.... I think the post may have been deleted. Could you perhaps clarify my question on this thread?

Comment: You can register there as a user. The discussion is pretty long.